# HTML table stretches and not allow overflow

Tags: html, css, mobile, vuejs2, css-tables

I'm currently building a web app with vuetify, and i'm having an issue with a table that is taking me a lot of time. I'd like to have like a scroller on mobile that allow you to see the table while keeping the aspect ratio and not stretching itself. I'll post the code down here and a picture of how the table is showed in a mobile view. I already tried adding `overflow: auto` and `overflow: scroll` but nothing it's changing. Can you help me?
Code:

```
<table id="tabellaPunteggi" style="overflow-x:auto;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="remove" colspan="3">Buca</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>=</td>
          <td>+/-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="remove" colspan="3">PAR</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>72</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="remove" colspan="3">Score</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>-9</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
<!-- Here is the table -->
```

And the css i tried using:

```
table#tabellaPunteggi{
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table#tabellaPunteggi tr td:not(.remove){
  width: 45px;
  height:45px;
}

table#tabellaPunteggi tr td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

table#tabellaPunteggi tr td.remove {
  width: 75px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks for your time! Have a nice day!

---

Edit (28/01/2022):
I tried using your answers (i really appreciate them), but there is like another problem.
I screenshot it so you can see clearly at this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd7l7.jpg
Thanks for your help!

Comment: add `min-width` for example `900px` to table;

Answer (score 0):

Set a min width on the td
you don't need the **:not(.remove)** since you set the width for **.remove** afterwards.

```
table#tabellaPunteggi tr td{
  min-width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}

table#tabellaPunteggi tr td.remove {
  min-width: 75px;
}
```

This will keep things as is
[image: demo showing code of table]

Comment: Hi, your answer was working but i updated the question because i realized that this caused another problem

Answer (score 0):

> just update your this css lines as i updated for you

`table#tabellaPunteggi{ border-collapse: collapse; overflow: hidden; min-width:500px }`

Comment: Hi, your answer was working but i updated the question because i realized that this caused another problem